# I can't connect to mysql DB connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have tried to connect to the DB mysql using php artisan migrate command and gives me this error

```
     Exception trace:
 1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused")
  /Users/hamad/Desktop/web/php/test/vendor/laravel/framework/srcIlluminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

 2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=laravel", "root", "", [])
  /Users/hamad/Desktop/web/php/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/.Connector.php:70
```

my set up in the env file is

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

and in config /database.php is

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

I have tried to use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 but did not work

thanks for your help

Comment: Are you able to login to your MySQL using the above credentials?

Comment: MySQL by default does not allow connecting to database via the `root` user. You should make another user and set the right privileges and use that user for accessing the database.

Answer (score 0):

I changed from xampp to mamp program and worked fine 
I think it is from the localserver and the port number 
xampp using 192.168.64.2 as localserver 
mamp uses 127.0.0.1 as localserver